# Dell firmware updates and newer Ubuntu versions

Tags: dell, firmware

I am running 16.04 on my Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition. The laptop came with Ubuntu pre-installed and that's exactly the reason I bought it.

One awesome feature is the Dell firmware updates showing up in the Software center. A simple click and reboot and I my laptop is running the latest and greatest firmware again.

Would I loose this when I manually install, say, 17.04? I would like to play with 17.04 but I am afraid I would need to keep a dual boot around  to get the firmware updates, is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dell firmware updates, if I am not wrong, are located in the `restricted` repository.

If you manually install Ubuntu 17.04, just type in a terminal `sudo add-apt-repository restricted`. Then, search for Dell firmware updates in GNOME Software center. It will work like Ubuntu 16.04, where you still receive firmware updates, unless Dell really decided to abandon Ubuntu's firmware updates (which in this case, Ubuntu 16.04 will also be affected.)

But the best choice, of course, is to keep your existing Ubuntu 16.04, install 17.04 alongside, so that even if you encounter problems, you can still fallback to 16.04 and ask something here.

Comment: There is no `non-free` repository in Ubuntu. That's a Debian thing. Ubuntu has `restricted` and `multiverse`.

Comment: Corrected?? I think...

Comment: `restricted` is usually already enabled by default. In any case, to enable one of those, you should do `sudo add-apt-repository restricted`, for example.

Comment: It seems that Dell has a lot of delay for pushing the firmware into that repository, at least for my computer (optiplex 7040), the firmware is four verion older than the firmware on the dell website.

Comment: Sorry. I think the repository stuff is plain wrong. The firmware updates in software center come from fwupd. Updating should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dell firmware updates come from [fwupd](https://fwupd.org/) repository and the corresponding [daemon](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd). Support for this repository was [introduced with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fwupd#Adoption).

It is safe to update. The service doesn't depend on a specific distro version (if its current enough for fwupd-support).

Answer (score -2):

Currently running Ubuntu 17.10 on XPS 9350 (which came with Windows) - firmware updates still coming in fine.